# Silex: Authentication system does not login

Tags: symfony, security, authentication, silex

I'm trying to implement the authentication system in my Silex project. However, I can't get it working. I've consulted so many websites that covered this system, but combining them all still does not get my project working.

First, I'm working in localhost in the folder ICT4LIFE. My whole project is in that folder. Now, this is my provider registering:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
            'security.firewalls' => array(
                'user' => array(
                    'pattern' => '^ICT4LIFE/user/',
                    'form' => array('login_path' => 'ICT4LIFE/', 'check_path' => '/user/login_check'),
                    'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/user/logout'),
                    'anonymous' => true,
                    'users' => function () use ($app) {
                        return new Models\UserProvider($app['db']);
                    }
                ),
            ),
            'security.access_rules' => array(
                array('^ICT4LIFE/user/', 'ROLE_USER')
            )
        ));
```

Then, there's the homepage of course in which we want to login:

```
$routes->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
        ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 3,'max' => 20))),
            'label' => 'Username',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Gebruikersnaam'),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label'),
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ))
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 5))),
            'label' => 'Password',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Wachtwoord'),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label'),
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Login',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'submit'),
        ])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $userProvider = new Models\UserProvider($app['db']);

        try {
            $duplicated = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($data['username']);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $duplicated = false;
        }

        if ($form->isValid() && !$duplicated) {
            $user = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User($data['username'], '', array('ROLE_USER'));

            $encoder = $app['security.encoder_factory']->getEncoder($user);

            $insertion = $app['db']->insert(
                'users',
                array(
                    'username'    => $data['username'],
                    'password' => $encoder->encodePassword($data['password'], $user->getSalt()),
                    'roles'    => 'ROLE_USER'
                )
            );
        }
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('form.twig', [
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);

})->bind('home');
```

You might also need my twig template, so, that's this one (form.twig):

```
{% extends 'templates/app.twig' %}

{% block main %}
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
        <p>Welcome {{ app.security.token.user.username }}!</p>
        <p><a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Log out</a></p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if form is defined %}
        <div class="BasicForm">
        <div class="BasicForm-heading">Provide your information</div>
        {% if error is defined %}
            {{ error | raw }}
        {% endif %}
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, the userprovider that I've found online:

```
<?php

namespace Models;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(Connection $conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', array(strtolower($username)));
        if (!$user = $stmt->fetch()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
        }

        return new User($user['username'], $user['password'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User';
    }
}
```

My website renders without a problem. I can't go to this link: http://localhost/ICT4LIFE/user/add
Because I then get redirected to my homepage. However, I can visit this link http://localhost/ICT4LIFE/user/register.

On my homepage, the form renders nicely. I can give my username and password. However, when I hit enter, the page seems to 'refresh'.

Here's a picture of my sql table called 'users'.
[image]

Also, this were the webpages that I've used to get here:

> https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle/issues/27
>   https://blog.andrewshell.org/figuring-out-silex-securityserviceprovider/
>   https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/security.html
>   http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/08/28/mysql-authentication-in-silex-the-php-micro-framework/
>   http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html

I believe that should be all you need to understand my problem. The rest doesn't have to do with the Security I believe. Please let me know what my problem is or if you need more information.

Comment: I can't understand your whole problem... First, why is there a form in your home page? Is it the login form? Why do you handle that form? Symfony Security Component does that for you... Second, what's your problem exactly, where you can go and where you can't. You should not be able to go to */ICT4LIFE/user/register* as this is a secured path demanding *ROLE_USER* role. Also, notice that your check path and log out are not in the secured area because your secured area starts with *ICT4LIFE* and your check path is inside */user/*

Comment: Well, It does not seem to handle it for me. And to your other question, for some reason, I AM able to go to the register page. But it starts to become a mess. You don't have a working example for me right? On github or something

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example right now. First of all, try to configure your paths correctly.  The *check_path* should be ```ICT4LIFE/user/login_check```. The logout should be ```ICT4LIFE/user/logout```. Then you should send your form to the login_check path, not to your home page. Change the action on the form to ```action="/ICT4LIFE/user/login_check```, then Silex will automatically handle that for you. See how that works, and then we can check what's happening with the roles.